# DocuSign AutoResponded RecipientEvent

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am building an envelope based webhook to receive status updates from DocuSign, rather than my current "polling" based method. I have the below code to create the RecipientEvent

```
RecipientEvent autoRespondedRecEvent = new RecipientEvent();
autoRespondedRecEvent.setRecipientEventStatusCode("AutoResponded");
recipientEvents.add(autoRespondedRecEvent);
```

I have similar RecipientEvents for Sent, Delivered, Completed, Declined, and AuthenticationFailed; however, all of these events work as intended, other than the 'AutoResponded' one.

Again, I am not using the account-level webhook, but the envelope based setup as have a fairly complex development/test environment. I have read another question on SO where the solution was a configuration setting

```
Return Recipient Auto Responded Status via Connect/Api
```

However, this solution does not apply in my case, as I'm not using an account-level webhook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a back-end setting that should still apply through envelope-level webhooks. I'd recommend opening a support case to have `Return Recipient Auto Responded Status in Connect/API` enabled for your account.

I'd recommend providing both your Demo and Production account IDs when you do so.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I did just that. After 4 hours on with support over the past two days, I learned that this "AutoResponded RecipientEvent" is not enabled by default, nor is there a way to enable it yourself, unless you're using the account-level connect configuration. The tech I spoke with said he requested that this be fixed going forwar, so hopefully further developers won't have this issue. Thanks for your response.