# DocuSign API : How to check if email notification was delivered successfully (no bounce back) or not?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get the status of envelope (document) email notification delivered to signer. If the notification was delivered successfully or not.

I am using **Create And Send Envelope** to sent document to DocuSing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check for:

1. Bounce email, that is a indication that the email bounced.
2. Envelope was opened. That is an indication that an email did not bounce.

There's no way to know for sure an email was not bounced if it was not opened by the user. So there's no way to really know for each envelope until such time that it didn't bounce (99% of bounce happen within seconds but sometimes it can take much longer)

[The status is AutoResponded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140312/docusign-autoresponded-recipientevent)

The best approach to use this information is using the [DocuSign connect webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/), and not using polling. So you get events to your service, you don't make API calls.